# Pandas Calculating Worked Duration and adding new column in end of existing csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to pandas And I got certain data of employees which have start and end date in date, month and year which is basically a column having lists.
Here is my data format is as follows  as extracted from csv column.

```
  data =[
   {
      "starts_at":{
         "day":1,
         "month":8,
         "year":2021
      },
      "ends_at":None
   },
   {
      "starts_at":{
         "day":1,
         "month":9,
         "year":2020
      },
      "ends_at":{
         "day":30,
         "month":4,
         "year":2021
      }
   },
   {
      "starts_at":None,
      "ends_at":{
         "day":30,
         "month":4,
         "year":2021
      }
   }
]
```

basically If `ends_at` is `None` than user is working currently(ongoing) and if end date is specified than user has ended contract with company.

There are certain fault data like `start_date` is None and `end_date` have dates these are also things I considered but all by python way.

I was told to do by pandas way but I think I am missing techniques of pandas rather than using double for loops in n*2 time complexity.

here is how I made my hands dirty with the pythonic way

```
from datetime import datetime

from datetime import date
from dateutil import relativedelta as rdelta
today = date.today()
df =pd.read_csv('/home/navaraj/Downloads/profile-details.csv')
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

df["experiences"] = df["experiences"].apply(eval)
 
print(df['experiences'])
for k in df["experiences"]:
    for x in k:
        starts=(x.get('starts_at'))
        if starts is not None:
            ends=(x.get('ends_at'))
            end_date_day=end_date_month=end_date_year=None
            status=None
            if ends is None:
                ends=today
                status="On going"
            else:
                end_date_day=ends['day']
                end_date_month=ends['month']
                end_date_year=ends['year']
                ends=datetime.strptime(f'{end_date_year}-{end_date_month}-{end_date_day}', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                status="ended"

                
            starts_day=starts['day']
            starts_month=starts['month']
            starts_year=starts['year']
            started=datetime.strptime(f'{starts_year}-{starts_month}-{starts_day}', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            rd = rdelta.relativedelta(ends,started)
            result="{0.years} years and {0.months} months".format(rd)
            print(result,status)
```

Problem and expection:
I just wanted those last line of data i.e `result` and working `status`(Ongoing or Ended) to be attached at the end of current csv  file for every users that I am working any Help will be really awesome.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just want to add those printed result at the end of csv column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'attached at the end' means at the end of each row, defining a function to use in a call to `pd.apply` is one pandas way to avoid explicitly looping over the df.

Below is for 'status', but the same can be done for 'result'

function

```py
def determine_status(row: pd.Series) -> str:
     if row['starts_at']:
             if row['ends_at']:
                     return "ended"
             return "On going"
```

applying to the df with this call, setting a new column equal to the result

```py
df.loc[:,'status'] = df.apply(determine_status, axis=1)
```

output

```
                              starts_at                                ends_at    status
0  {'day': 1, 'month': 8, 'year': 2021}                                   None  On going
1  {'day': 1, 'month': 9, 'year': 2020}  {'day': 30, 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}     ended
2                                  None  {'day': 30, 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}      None
```